# How to access files on UNIX server from a laptop running Windows and R?

Tags: r, ssh

In work all my data files are on UNIX server. Usually I use SSH client (such as PUTTY) on my Windows laptop to transfer data files from UNIX server to my laptop first and then run R locally to do analysis.

The question is if it's possible to use R directly access files on UNIX server. I understand that R can go to a URL and fetch data. Can I do the same to my UNIX server? If yes how?

Many Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but a system administrator question, on-topic on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3):

You can install Samba on your Unix/Linux server and mount it as standard windows share.

You can also use software like WinSCP to provide virtual explorer-like view, but this will not be real file access - at least R will not be able to make use of it.

There is also [sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs) which should be able to provide real mount over ssh, but to be frank I did not have much luck trying to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RCurl with OpenSSL for Windows..

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to install RStudio Server on the server. That way, you can run RStudio in a web browser on your windows machine. R is than running on the server. This ofcourse only works if you have root access to the server, or can convince the administrator.

Alternatively, you could use `rsync` to regularly sync a set of files with the server. For using `rsync` under Windows you could take a look at MinGW or Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Putty` to `ssh` to your UNIX server, open `terminal` or `emacs` (`ESS`), open `R` to do any analysis. I guess your UNIX server should have `R` installed.